Sum amounts based on criteria for unique combinations of fields in an Excel Table
I have a Table in Excel 365 called MyLongData that contains multiple rows. I would like to come up with a formula that tracks claims, where a claim is defined as a unique combination of fields [Accident Date], [Claimant Name], [Location].
I want to add up the [Amount] field for claims where [Amount]>10000,
furthermore, I want to restrict it to where field [Year] = 2023.
So to summarize, I would like to add up [Amount] given [Amount]>10000 grouped by combination of [Accident Date], [Claimant Name], [Location] in a table MyLongData.
Simple example:



Accident Date
Claimant Name
Location
Year
Amount




1/1/2020
Jake
Denver
2021
20000


2/1/2023
Jill
Seattle
2023
9950


2/1/2023
Jill
Seattle
2023
100


5/6/2023
Blake
Miami
2023
5000



I want to return 10050 (the sum of records 2 and 3, which are a single claim that exceeds the 10000 threshold).
I managed to figure out the formula for the COUNTS, which I believe is correct:
=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(
MyLongData[Accident Date]&MyLongData[Location]&MyLongData[Claimant Name],
(MyLongData[Year]=2023)*(SUMIFS(MyLongData[Amount],
MyLongData[Accident Date],MyLongData[Accident Date],
MyLongData[Location],MyLongData[Location],
MyLongData[Claimant Name],
MyLongData[Claimant Name])>10000)))),0)

But I can't get the formula to add up the amounts.
I'd prefer a single (however complex) formula, but I can also resort to a Pivot Table approach, if that's the only way.

Here is one way of achieving the desired output:


=LET(
     _SumByYear, SUMIFS(Amount,Accident_Date,Accident_Date,
                               Claimant_Name,Claimant_Name,
                               Location,Location,Year,2023),
     UNIQUE(FILTER(HSTACK(DROP(MyLongData,,-1),_SumByYear),
                   _SumByYear>10000,0)))


Or Better with using GROUPBY() if applicable:
=LET(
     _Group, GROUPBY(MyLongData[[Accident Date]:[Year]],Amount,SUM,,0,,Year=2023),
     FILTER(_Group, TAKE(_Group,,-1)>10000,0))


NOTE: Firstly, using Structured References aka Tables, secondly to make easier to read have defined those references with their respective column heads. Please ensure to change the references or cell ranges etc as per your suit. GROUPBY() function works with MS365 Office Insiders Version Exclusively. 


So simple with SUMIFS!

There is a minor flaw in the solution provided. The UNIQUE function kicks out two identical records and only keeps one, but they should be added up instead. I believe the fix is to add a row index into the unique mix, like this:
=LET(      _SumByYear, SUMIFS(Amount,Accident_Date,Accident_Date,                                Claimant_Name,Claimant_Name,                                Location,Location,Year,2023),      UNIQUE(FILTER(HSTACK(DROP(MyLongData,,-1),_SumByYear,ROW(MyLongData)),                    _SumByYear>10000,0)))

Pretty sure it can be shorter, just to get an idea:
=LET(a,A1:D4,b,INDEX(a,,1),c,INDEX(a,,2),d,INDEX(a,,3),e,INDEX(a,,4),f,UNIQUE(FILTER(a,e=2023)),g,E1:E4,h,HSTACK(f,BYROW(f,LAMBDA(x,SUM(FILTER(g,(b=INDEX(x,,1))*(c=INDEX(x,,2))*(d=INDEX(x,,3))))))),FILTER(h,INDEX(h,,5)>10000))



Thanks! This worked in testing, but my real data has columns in different places (there are extra columns in between all the columns I gave), and I had a hard time lining up the INDEX numbers. I think I messed up the INDEX references inside the LAMBDA function, but I couldn't figure out how to fix them; I don't think they coincide with the index of the original data. I was getting results, but they didn't add up by manual inspection.

My mistake I've build a formula not using table references . Anyway you've got very good answer already!
